# Error (check link)

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad English. I'm young and learning it at the moment.

Check the errors on http://www.tijmen.snaphost.nl/. How can I fix it? I already checked everything on Google.

```
public function open($save_path, $name)
{
    if ( ! is_dir($save_path))
    {
        if ( ! mkdir($save_path, 0700, TRUE))
        {
            throw new Exception("Session: Configured save path '".$this->_config['save_path']."' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.");
        }
    }
    elseif ( ! is_writable($save_path))
    {
        throw new Exception("Session: Configured save path '".$this->_config['save_path']."' is not writable by the PHP process.");
    }

    $this->_config['save_path'] = $save_path;
    $this->_file_path = $this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        .$name // we'll use the session cookie name as a prefix to avoid collisions
        .($this->_config['match_ip'] ? md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) : '');

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You should post your code, but generally it looks like you specified a path that does not exist yet. And you might want to take a look at your imagick extension for php since that connot be found.

Comment: I don't know which code. That is the problem. I'm new as developer, I'm trying to learn everything. Most of the time I can fix my errors, but this time I can't. Thanks for the information.

Comment: It's a big file. I don't know where the error is.. I'm new into PHP. Sorry.

Comment: I found the mkdir. Check the home post.

Comment: <Message: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.> Check that $save_path is not empty or != '' or != ' '

Comment: Thanks it's fixed!